# How to bind class with constructor in Guice

Tags: constructor, binding, guice

I want to bind MyImpl to Multibinding. But MyImpl's constructor takes parameter.

```
final Multibinder<MyInterface> binder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MyInterface.class)
binder.addBinding().to(MyImpl.class);

public MyImpl(Boolean myParam) ...
```

I do not want to @Inject it because it's say boolean, which can be occasionally injected somewhere else. So. I can introduce some Enum and inject it instead, how then to do this? Or can I better just write somehow

```
binder.addBinding().to(MyImpl.class, true);
binder.addBinding().to(MyImpl2.class, false);
```

or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to @Inject it because it's say boolean, which can be occasionally injected somewhere else.
>   To avoid this, use Named Annotations.

**Solution One:**

```java
@Inject
public TextEditor(@Named("OpenOffice") SpellChecker spellChecker) { ...}
```

Here is the binding code:

```java
bind(SpellChecker.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("OpenOffice")).to(OpenOfficeWordSpellCheckerImpl.class);
```

**Solution Two:**

Load java-properties in a module and use the java-prop-names:

```java
private static Properties loadProperties(String name){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(name);
    try {
        properties.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }finally {
        if(is != null){
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException dontCare) { }
        }
    }
    return properties;
}

protected void configure() {
    try{
        Properties gameProperties = loadProperties("game.properties");
        Names.bindProperties(binder(),gameProperties);
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){
        addError("Could not configure Game Properties");
    };

}
```